# Does the new iPhone 5 Lightning connector still provide serial output (or does it when the dock connector adapter?)?

Tags: iphone, ipod, lightning

I'm working on an iPhone DIY dock kit, that exposes the serial connection for controlling the music playback controls through the serial port (Apple Accessory Protocol).

Does anyone know if the AAP serial commands still work with the new Lightning connector, or even better, with the dock adapter (since I'm not going to be shelling out for Apple's hardware developer program just yet)? I've had a hard time googling it successfully, other than that the adapter works with some other hardware and things like the MintyBoost DIY charger.

Comment: It's not quite an answer, but http://www.redpark.com/c2ttl_FAQs.html suggests that with the right electronics, it will be possible to get a serial connection through a Lightning port.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know if this is what your're looking for but anyways.
Momentarily it is a work in progress. I hope we'll get some info soon.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f8aUUHrHKc

P.S. I am not affiliated with this, I was just looking for it.

Comment: As far as I know, this should be the same thing. But, as I'm not in the adapter program either, I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: @awesomebig1
I am not sure if you really wanted to say something, or just earning posts for nothing.

The thing is, iphone and this new lightning port, are more hard to break in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should talk with somebody with access to that **API**, an Apple Hardware Developer. The program is called **MFi** Program.

As I know, there is no easy go on that, as they keep things really private. 
And it costs a lot of money per year to have access to hardware details.

But I hope, you can find some info out there, google harder.